# why ado.net entity data model changed in vs 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i created two samples of windows application

first on vs 2010 and .net framework 4 and 
second on vs2012 and .net framework 4 too.

i add ado.net entity data model to them but this model is deferente on theme first have this files:

```
1-mymodel.Designer.cs
```

second :

```
1-mymodel.Context.tt
2-mymodel.Designer.cs
3-Mymodel.tt
4-mymodel.edms.diagram
```

why thee are deference is that new in vs 2022 and it is important for me that first has default constructor that let you create your own connection string but second hasn't any constructor,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 5 operates by convention rather than by configuration.

Create your own context that inherits `DbContext` and pass in the connection string like so:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext 
{
    public MyContext()
        : base([myConnectionString])
    {
    }
}
```