# how to set serializable attribute on my entities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

my site is on a web farm for this i used my session in mode="StateServer" in this mode objects must have serialize able attribute ,
i used ado.net entity data model it works fine and i have no problems with these.

i update my project to vs 2012 but my ef stay on 4.1 because my host don not support  upper version of  ef, when i deleted my entity and create it again it's structure changed you can look at this [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029667/why-ado-net-entity-data-model-changed-in-vs-2012) but in new model the serialize able attribute is unavailable and do not created automatically by ef i look at codes and add it by myself but if i recreate my model all of them will be delete how can i handle this problem?

thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

Your Entity Framework models are [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you can simply create another file (per object or containing all objects) that have the attribute.  They will be combined with the Entity Framework classes as long as the name spaces are the same between the two classes.

```
[Serializable]
public partial class MyEntity
{
}
```

Comment: i had a problem in new model in vs 2012 by connection string and create this class
but serializable do not works by this way
but thanks for your answer